# Error al conectarse a instancia de SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Estoy dando mantenimiento a aplicaciones que yo no realice, de la cual hay una instancia en el `Web.config`, a lo cual desearía conectarme para revisar la configuración, esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<add name="ConexionAdvantage" connectionString="Data Source=\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\instancia\inf.add;User ID=adssys;ServerType=REMOTE;" providerName="Advantage.Data.Provider"/>
```

Y intente solo colocando solamente la IP del servidor sin lograr conectarme.

Estoy tratando de acceder así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respuesta del sql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás en la misma red que el server?

Comment: Así es, inclusive estoy en el server con el sql

Comment: y que error sale?

Comment: Que no se puede establecer la conexión al sql server, adjunto arriba la respuesta